# Connecting Multiple Buttons to one action?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have multiple UIButtons in my app. I also use interfacebuilder. In my .h i have something like this

```
  IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed;
```

Then In my m i want to do something like this

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {


if (theButtonIpressed == button1) 

{

// do something if 

}

}
```

The problem is I don't have something called "theButtonIpressed" so I cant do this. What should my if statement look like? I don't want to make a -(IBAction) for each button. Is there something that I can determine which button was pressed? Thanks!

Thanks,

-David

Comment: @David - why not have other `IBAction`s? Your code will be easier to maintain with multiple methods.

Comment: not if they all do very similar things. that leads to a lot of repeated code, right?

Comment: Follow this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050516/how-to-connect-multiple-buttons-in-a-storyboard-to-a-single-action/24842728#24842728

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also set the tag property for each button in the interface builder and then use it to find out which button was pressed....  This also means that you don't need to define all your button references (UIButton) and keep track of them in code....

```
- (void) doSomething:(id)sender {

    int buttonPressed = [sender tag];

    switch (buttonPressed) {
       case 0:....
       // etc
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your `- (IBAction)buttonPressed` to:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed: (UIButton *) buttonIpressed
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button`

But if you're doing something different for each button then the **proper** way to do it is to create separate IBActions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag values for each buttons

```
 IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
 button1.tag = 100;
 IBOutlet UIButton *button2; 
 button2.tag = 200;
 IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
 button3.tag = 300;

 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
   if ([sender tag]==100) 
   {
     NSLOG("button1");
   }
   else if([sender tag]==200)
   {
     NSLOG("button2");
   }
   else {
     NSLOG("button3");
   }

}
```